# Use Option<&mut> 2 times

Tags: memory-management, rust

The following program compiles fine:

```
fn write_u16(bytes: &mut Vec<u8>, value: u16) {
    bytes.push((value >> 8) as u8);
    bytes.push(value as u8);
}

fn write_u32(bytes: &mut Vec<u8>, value: u32) {
    write_u16(bytes, (value >> 16) as u16);
    write_u16(bytes, value as u16);
}
```

now I'll change bytes type to Option<&mut Vec>:

```
fn write_u16(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u16) {
    if let Some(bytes) = bytes_opt {
        bytes.push((value >> 8) as u8);
        bytes.push(value as u8);
    }
}

fn write_u32(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u32) {
    write_u16(bytes_opt, (value >> 16) as u16);
    write_u16(bytes_opt, value as u16);
}
```

The program doesn't compile now:

```
main.rs:10:15: 10:24 error: use of moved value: `bytes_opt`
main.rs:10     write_u16(bytes_opt, value as u16);
                         ^~~~~~~~~
main.rs:9:15: 9:24 note: `bytes_opt` moved here because it has type `core::option::Option<&mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>>`, which is non-copyable
main.rs:9     write_u16(bytes_opt, (value >> 16) as u16);
                        ^~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I don't really understand, why I can't use Option twice and how do I solve this problem?

The only way I can imagine to solve this problem is:

```
fn write_u32(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u32) {
    if let Some(bytes) = bytes_opt {
        write_u16(Some(bytes), (value >> 16) as u16);
        write_u16(Some(bytes), value as u16);
    } else {
        write_u16(None, (value >> 16) as u16);
        write_u16(None, value as u16);
    }
}
```

but that's not very nice code.

Comment: If `write_u16(None, _)` is a noop, I question the use of an `Option` at all; `write_u16(option, value)` can be `option.map(|bytes| write_16(bytes, value))`. I would imagine you would normally be dealing directly with the vector and not with an option.

Comment: It's not a noop, it's a simplified example. In my code I use `pos: &mut usize` which specifies where to write the value (and returns position after last written byte) and `&mut [u8]` instead of `&mut Vec`. And I use `None` to find out how much bytes I will write before actual writing, so no reallocations will needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I suspect in this case you should not be doing this (as commented already), it is possible to reborrow mutable references for this sort of a case where it is safe:

```rust
fn write_u32(mut bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u32) {
    write_u16(bytes_opt.as_mut().map(|x| &mut **x), (value >> 16) as u16);
    write_u16(bytes_opt, value as u16);
}
```

The `bytes_opt.as_mut().map(|x| &mut **x)` could also be written `match bytes_opt { Some(&mut ref mut x) => Some(x), None => None, }`. A pretty mind-bending pattern (read it from left to right: `&mut`—dereference the contained value, `ref mut`—and then take a new mutable reference to it), but it works and avoids the ownership issue.

Comment: Thanks. That works but it seems too complicated for me, I'll probably redesign my API. I have too much `C` thinking I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you they key things:

> `bytes_opt` moved here because it has type `core::option::Option<&mut collections::vec::Vec<u8>>`, which is non-copyable

Your function signature states that it is going to *consume* the argument:

```
fn write_u16(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u16)
//                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, by consuming it, it also *consumes* the mutable reference. If you had another type like `Option<u8>` or `Option<&Vec<u8>>`, then the compiler could just insert an implicit copy of the variable for you. However, you aren't allowed to make copies of **mutable references**, because then you would have *mutable aliases*, which the compiler disallows for memory-safety reasons.

When you pass just the `&mut Vec<u8>`, the compiler is able to track the reference and see that only one item has the reference at a time, so it allows it. However, it is unable to track that when the mutable reference is embedded in another type.

To actually get it to work, it's a bit ugly, with more `mut` qualifiers than I would like:

```
fn write_u16(bytes_opt: &mut Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u16) {
    if let Some(ref mut bytes) = *bytes_opt {
        bytes.push((value >> 8) as u8);
        bytes.push(value as u8);
    }
}

fn write_u32(mut bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u32) {
    write_u16(&mut bytes_opt, (value >> 16) as u16);
    write_u16(&mut bytes_opt, value as u16);
}
```

Prompted by @ChrisMorgan, I got something that fits your original API:

```
fn write_u16(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u16) {
    if let Some(bytes) = bytes_opt {
        bytes.push((value >> 8) as u8);
        bytes.push(value as u8);
    }
}

fn write_u32(bytes_opt: Option<&mut Vec<u8>>, value: u32) {
    if let Some(bytes) = bytes_opt {
        write_u16(Some(bytes), (value >> 16) as u16);
        write_u16(Some(bytes), value as u16);
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking `&mut Option<&mut Vec<u8>>` is definitely worse than reconstructing the `Option<&mut Vec<u8>>` each time, because the API is harmed.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan thanks for the gentle nudge in a better direction.

Comment: Your semantics in second case is slightly different, you don't call `write_u16` with `None`. I actually need that all methods called with `Some` or `None`, whatever they have. In my real code method `write_u16` is slightly more complex and doing useful work even with `None` passed.